# Scheduling airflow TaskGroup throws AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, python-3.8, airflow-2.x

So I am creating task in a TaskGroup and am trying to add them in my dag sequence of tasks but it is throwing this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/Users/abc/projects/abc/airflow_dags/dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/vmd-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1234, in set_downstream
    self._set_relatives(task_or_task_list, upstream=False)
  File "/Users/abc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/vmd-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1178, in _set_relatives
    task_object.update_relative(self, not upstream)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_relative'
```

I am creating my task group and tasks like this:

```
def get_task_group(dag, task_group):
    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='t1', dag=dag, task_group=task_group)
    t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='t2', dag=dag, task_group=task_group)
    t3 = DummyOperator(task_id='t3', dag=dag, task_group=task_group)
    t4 = DummyOperator(task_id='t4', dag=dag, task_group=task_group)
    t5 = DummyOperator(task_id='t5', dag=dag, task_group=task_group)
    t_list = [t2, t3, t4]
    t1.set_downstream(t_list)
    t5.set_upstream(t_list)


with DAG('some_dag', default_args=args) as dag:
    with TaskGroup(group_id=f"run_model_tasks", dag=dag) as tg:
      run_model_task_group = get_task_group(dag, tg)

    a1 = DummyOperator(task_id='a1', dag=dag)
    a2 = DummyOperator(task_id='a2', dag=dag)
    a3 = DummyOperator(task_id='a3', dag=dag)
    a4 = DummyOperator(task_id='a4', dag=dag)

    a1.set_downstream(a2)
    a2.set_downstream(run_model_task_group)
    a3.set_upstream(run_model_task_group)
    a3.set_downstream(a4)
```

If I remove the task groups and leave task group task from sequencing by removing the lines

```
a2.set_downstream(run_model_task_group)
a3.set_upstream(run_model_task_group)
```

I can see that a1, a2 a3 & a4 are sequenced properly and I can the disconnected `run_model_task_group` tasks, but as soon as I add it in the sequence, I get the aforementioned error. 
Can anyone guide me what might be happening here?
[image]

**Note that I am using the function taking `dag` and `task_group` parameters to create task group tasks because I want to create the same set of tasks for another dag too.**

```
Python Version: 3.8.8
Airflow Version: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_relative'`It's happening because `run_model_task_group` its `None` outside of the scope of the `With` block, which is expected Python behaviour.

Without changing things too much from what you have done so far, you could refactor `get_task_group()` to return a `TaskGroup` object, like this:

```py
def get_task_group(dag, group_id):

    with TaskGroup(group_id=group_id, dag=dag) as tg:
        t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='t1', dag=dag)
        t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='t2', dag=dag)
        t3 = DummyOperator(task_id='t3', dag=dag)
        t4 = DummyOperator(task_id='t4', dag=dag)
        t5 = DummyOperator(task_id='t5', dag=dag)
        t_list = [t2, t3, t4]
        t1.set_downstream(t_list)
        t5.set_upstream(t_list)
    return tg
```

In the DAG definition simply call it with:

`run_model_task_group = get_task_group(dag, "run_model_tasks")`

The resultant graph view looks like this:

[image: graph_view]

DAG definition:

```py
with DAG('some_dag',
         default_args=default_args,
         start_date=days_ago(2),
         schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
    # with TaskGroup(group_id=f"run_model_tasks", dag=dag) as tg:
    #     run_model_task_group = get_task_group(dag, )
    run_model_task_group = get_task_group(dag, "run_model_tasks")
    a1 = DummyOperator(task_id='a1', dag=dag)
    a2 = DummyOperator(task_id='a2', dag=dag)
    a3 = DummyOperator(task_id='a3', dag=dag)
    a4 = DummyOperator(task_id='a4', dag=dag)

    a1.set_downstream(a2)
    a2.set_downstream(run_model_task_group)
    a3.set_upstream(run_model_task_group)
    a3.set_downstream(a4)
```

Finally, considering using bitwise operator instead of `set_downstream` and `set_upstream`, it's the recommend way and also less verbose [source here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.4/concepts/dags.html#task-dependencies).

Let me know if that worked for you.

*Tested with: Airflow version: 2.1.4, Python 3.8.10*